# Best way to use javascript promise chaining in order to have truly asynchronous sequence of functions?

Tags: javascript

I've read an article at https://javascript.info/promise-chaining which explains some great ways of using promises.

However, I'm unsure of which method I should use if I were to have multiple functions I wanted to run, but for each one to only begin once the previous function has totally finished.

Taken and modified (mainly by removing the setTimeout from the resolve) from the article's first example, would this be enough to do what I described?

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  resolve();

}).then(function() {

  // first function here

}).then(function() {

  // second function here

}).then(function() {

  // third function here

});
```

Or would I have to do what is later on in the article described as "returning promises", as below?

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  resolve();

}).then(function() {

  // first function here

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });

}).then(function() {

  // second function here

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });

}).then(function() {

  // third function here

});
```

Alternatively, is there any simpler or better way of achieving what I want?

Comment: A way more readable approach is to use async/await.

Comment: If you have `promise.then(a).then(b)`, function `a` always runs before function `b`, but be careful of whether there’s something *else* function `a` does apart from just running that `b` needs to wait for (e.g. create another promise, which is when you would return that promise). Also, you probably don’t need to use the `Promise` constructor that much. Even for examples, `Promise.resolve()` is equivalent to `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(); })`.

Comment: @ChrisCousins would you be able to give an example of how it would be achieved using async/await? Thanks!

Comment: @Ry- so the first example should satisfy what I'm looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend async/await with Promise.all. Example:

```
function action1() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('This is an action that takes 2 seconds'), 2000); 
  });
}

function action2() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('This is an action that takes 5 seconds'), 5000); 
  });
}

function action3() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('This is an action that takes 1 second'), 1000); 
  });
}

executeActions = async function() {
  try {
    const [act1, act2, act3] = await Promise.all([action1(), action2(), action3()]);
    console.log(act1 + '\n', act2 + '\n', act3);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

executeActions();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a function callback in `then`,

```
.then(
  function() { // function callback
    // some code
  }
)
```

you don't need to return new `Promise`, you can return just some value and this value by default will be wrapped to `Promise`

BAD:

```
.then(function() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // NOT need to create promise 
      resolve(1)
   })
})
```

GOOD:

```
.then(function() {
   return 1; // in `than` function callback by default return new promise
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If the function you want to run in the `then` callback is synchronous you may just call/include it directly. If the function is again asynchronous and you want to wait for it to complete, you should return a promise which gets resolved when it's done.